# Cannot link a Qt console application with Openscengrapgh

Tags: qt, opengl, openscenegraph

i have succesfully integrated Openscenegraph with Visual Studio 2008. The sample "cessna.osg" given as an example runs fine in VS2008 as a console program. But when i try to run the same code as console in Qt it gives an error. I have built Openscenegraph 3.0 with CMAKE using VS2008 compiler with Qt option on windows7 64 bit. In Qt i am using the version QT 4.7.4 Desktop-MSVC2008 (QtSDK). My Qt .pro file looks like this...

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = OSGTEST (name of the console project)
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH +=C:\OPENSCENEGRAPH\INCLUDE\

LIBS +=C:\OPENSCENEGRAPH\LIB\
-lOpenThreadsd\
-losgd\
-losgDBd\
-losgUtild\
-losgViewerd\
```

i am using the same library and include file paths in VS2008 IDE as mentioned above.

the main.cpp file looks like dis...(which is the same as in VS2008 IDE)

```
#include <osgDB/ReadFile>
#include <osgViewer/Viewer>


int main()
{
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::Node> root = osgDB::readNodeFile("cessna.osg");
    osgViewer::Viewer viewer;
    viewer.setSceneData( root.get() );
    return viewer.run();
}
```

the error i am getting is ...

```
error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\OPENSCENEGRAPH\LIB.obj'
```

Guide me so that i can run the application as console. Or is there any other way i can run Openscenegraph apps on Qt console?

Comment: Does 'C:\OPENSCENEGRAPH\LIB.obj' exist?

Comment: no...C:\OPENSCENEGRAPH\LIB is just the path to the debug libraries i have built using CMAKE..

Comment: Change `LIBS +=C:\OPENSCENEGRAPH\LIB\ ` to `LIBS +=-LC:\OPENSCENEGRAPH\LIB\ `.

Comment: I highly recommend CMake over Qt project files. It makes integration with different libraries a lot easier.

Comment: @pmr: Interesting.  I use qmake for Qt builds but can't say I'm a fan of it.  Does CMake include built-in support for Qt quirks like the MOC pass, or you you have to set that up yourself?

Comment: @timday Built-in. http://qt-project.org/quarterly/view/using_cmake_to_build_qt_projects

Comment: @pmr....thanx for the link...clears many doubts of mine about Qt..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment is correct, you want:

> LIBS +=-LC:\OPENSCENEGRAPH\LIB\ -lOpenThreadsd -losgd ...

The -L tells qmake the following argument is a folder to search for libraries, not a library itself.